# Prove that $A \times B = B \times A $ if and only if $A = B \lor A = \emptyset \lor B = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $A \times B = B \times A $ if and only if $A = B \lor A =  \emptyset \lor B = \emptyset $ 
So, I need to prove that 
$$A\times B = B \times A \iff A = B \lor A = \emptyset \lor B = \emptyset$$
It is easy to show the right-to-left implication. The problem begins when I want to show the left-to-right one. I tried using the axiom of extentionality, but that did not work. What kind of trick should I use to prove that the relation from left to right holds as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A \neq B \wedge A \neq \emptyset \wedge B \neq \emptyset$

Then $(\exists x \in A\wedge x \notin B) \vee (\exists x \in B\wedge x \notin A)$

We suppose WLoG $(\exists a \in A\wedge a \notin B)$

We also have $\exists b \in B$

This implies
$$(a,b)\in A\times B$$
But $$(a,b)\notin B\times A$$
Because $$a\notin B$$

Therefore $A\times B\neq B\times A $

Comment: To be clear this proves the implication to the right. The other way  should be obvious.